# How to publish page on github?

Tags: html, github, publish

I need to publish the page for study pupuses, but I have this error:

> 404
> File not found
>
> The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file.
>
> If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL as well as any file permissions.
> For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file.
>
> Read the full documentation for more information about using GitHub Pages.

The file what I try to publish: https://github.com/andrzejhnatiuk/gramedyczna.github.io/tree/main/index

I use github desktop.

I tryed randomly change everything in setting -> pages but nothing works.
[image]

How can I publish this site?

Answer (score 1):

A repo called `andrzejhnatiuk/gramedyczna.github.io` is not enough to publish a GitHub Pages site under https://gramedyczna.github.io; you would need the (at present non-existent) user or organization https://github.com/gramedyczna to create and publish a repository https://github.com/gramedyczna/gramedyczna.github.io to do achieve that.

If just anyone could publish a site using someone else's username, some havoc would ensue.

Answer (score 0):

The github repo name should be your github's username or like this:

```
github.com/<username>/<username>.github.io
```